# complete information about the components like:- websocket,polling, etc

Tags: botframework, direct-line-botframework

I want a descriptive information about websocket, polling, s, t, watermark, redux usage, etc used in maicrosoft webchat. i was unable to find the exact page to look into these parts in in deep way.

please provide me the complete information and if links are available provide me ASAP.thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

WebSockets, polling, secret, token, and watermark are all options for the [DirectLine-JS](https://www.npmjs.com/package/botframework-directlinejs) npm package that Web Chat uses to connect to the conversation.

```js
import { DirectLine } from 'botframework-directlinejs';

const directLine = new DirectLine({
    secret: /* put your Direct Line secret here */,
    token: /* or put your Direct Line token here (supply secret OR token, not both) */,
    domain: /* optional: if you are not using the default Direct Line endpoint, e.g. if you are using a region-specific endpoint, put its full URL here */
    webSocket: /* optional: false if you want to use polling GET to receive messages. Defaults to true (use WebSocket). */,
    pollingInterval: /* optional: set polling interval in milliseconds. Default to 1000 */,
});
```

Web Chat's Redux-Sagas uses the DirectLine connection to monitor for events from the bot. When the DirectLine object observes an event, the Sages dispatch an event to the Redux store to update the conversation state. You can add a Redux Middleware to create custom events when different actions are dispatched to the store. For example, when the Direct Line Connection is `Online`, the sagas dispatch a `DIRECT_LINE/CONNECT_FULLED` event to the store. In the middleware, you can filter for the connect action and dispatch a backchannel welcome message when the conversation begins. For more details take a look at the [Backchannel Welcome Message](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/tree/master/samples/15.d.backchannel-send-welcome-event) and [Customizing Redux Actions](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/tree/master/samples/11.customization-redux-actions) Web Chat Samples.